# Docker environment variable security

Tags: security, environment-variables, docker

I have a docker application that I need to pass a secure piece of information to, since it uses a passphrase to encrypt/decrypt stored data. I'm trying to figure out how safe it is to use an environment variable to pass in this information. I know that if I use

```
docker run -e passphrase="secretkey123" --name containername imagename
```

Then the value can be found by:

```
docker inspect containername
```

Thus it must be stored somewhere on disk (in /var/lib/docker I assume). Is there any more secure way to pass an environment variable to docker? Should I use a temporary file in a volume linked to the host filesystem instead? Is there a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regardless of where it is stored, it is clearly accessible via "docker inspect". I think it boils down to how secure you want it to be. For example, you can instead have a shared volume with file permissions to restrict access to a password file on disk. Or you could have a socker/ssh/etc to avoid putting the password into a file on disk at all. It just depends on how secure you really want to be.

I do note that if you have say a web server running in a container, I assume if someone breaks out of the web server they can only access what the container can access (and not the host OS where docker is running).

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer doesn’t point out that you can require root access for interacting with the Docker process / assets.

Requiring root access (and using shell interpolated values, to obscure the execute commands from being shown in ps), will secure your secrets to online access. Offline, the file system should be encrypted, or ephemeral containers can use a RAM disk for container storage.